# Orientdb hangs for an insert query with cluster

Tags: python, orientdb

I am a newbie to OrientDB. We were trying to create multiple clusters on orientDB. The code snippet we were using to implement the same is as shown below

```
client.command("ALTER CLASS sample_class ADDCLUSTER sample_cluster")
client.command("insert into sample_class cluster  sample_cluster set x = '1'")
```

The first command executes fine. But orientDB hangs while trying to execute the second command. I was running these sql queries using the python package for OrientDB 'pyorient'.Can someone help me to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you're looking for is:

```
insert into cluster:sample_cluster set x = '1'
```

See [this link](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Insert.html#insert-in-a-different-cluster).